# Thymeleaf - Wont display 1 of 6 getter-methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

So, I'm doing an assignment where we have to use Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. I need to display the bio box of a user in the system, but it doesn't allow me. I can easily System.out.print the bio, but I can not make it show on my html page.
Controller looks like this:

```
@GetMapping("/myProfile")
public String myProfile(HttpServletRequest request, Model model){
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    model.addAttribute("userToDisplay", userToDisplay);
    System.out.println("Printing from myProfile "+ user.getBio());
    if(user!=null){
        return "myProfile";
    } else{
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

And the relevant HTML part looks like:

```
         <div class="textarea">
            <form action="/infoPost" method="post" id="bioForm">
                <textarea id="infoBox" name="bio" rows="10" cols="50" th:field="${userToDisplay.getBio()}" placeholder="Describe yourself.. "></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Gem Description" class="submitDescription">
            </form>
        </div>
```

I have absolutely no idea what should be causing this. As I can make it show users full name, username, email etc. But not the bio, even though its printable.
Anyone has any ideas?

Best regards

Comment: What exactly is the `userToDisplay` object in your controller? Is that supposed to be `user`?

Comment: @Troley userToDisplay is my object of my user-model. the user model class only contains constructors and getters/setters :)

Comment: Oh damn, I just realized that I should be using the User object that is the session.. Thanks for your question which solved it for me :D have a good one!

Comment: Ah, well that's great that it fixed it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrongfully used the wrong object of my user model. I should of course use the session user.